# 'Else If' is a reserved keyword. It must be in uppercase (ELSE IF) when used as a marker with 'Run Keyword If' in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I'm getting the following error 
'Else If' is a reserved keyword. It must be in uppercase (ELSE IF) when used as a marker with 'Run Keyword If'

Code snipet is as follows... Can anyone help me with the resolution? Thanks

```
Run Keyword If    '${intf_type}' == 'l3'    Run Keywords
            Execute         Load Configuration      @{target}[0]      commit_comment=configure isis   data=set interfaces xe-0/0/2:0 unit 0 family inet address 10.0.0.1/24 ${\n} set interfaces xe-0/0/2:0 unit 0 family iso ${\n} set protocols isis interface xe-0/0/2:0.0 ${\n} set protocols isis interface lo0.0                format=set
            Sleep   30s
            ELSE IF    '${intf_type}' == 'irb'    Run Keywords
            Execute         Load Configuration       @{target}[0]    commit_comment=configure isis    data=set interfaces xe-0/0/2:0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode trunk ${\n} set interfaces xe-0/0/2:0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members v-10 ${\n} set interfaces irb unit 10 family inet address 10.0.0.1/24 ${\n} set interfaces irb unit 10 family iso ${\n} set protocols isis interface irb.10 ${\n} set protocols isis interface lo0.0 ${\n} set vlans v-10 vlan-id 10 ${\n} set vlans v-10 l3-interface irb.10       format=set
```

Comment: Could you format your code clearly?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format the code so it is readable. You can find help doing so by clicking the ? at the upper right corner of the text box while you're making that edit. You can preview the code in realtime (WYSIWYG) during the edit by looking just below the area where you're typing the text as you're typing.

Answer (score 6):

It is hard to read your code snippet because it does not show formatting. ELSE IF requires correct formatting. It is important to have ELSE IF in same block and "..." in beginning of line is very important. Here are two examples, do they help you at all:

```
Set Variable
    ${x}=      Set Variable    1
    ${var1}=    Run Keyword If    ${x} == 2    Set Variable    2
    ...         ELSE IF     ${x} == 1    Set Variable    1
    Log    ${var1}

Run Keyword
    ${x}=    Set Variable    1
    Run Keyword If    ${x} == 2    Log    2
    ...    ELSE IF     ${x} == 1    Log    1
```